# What does this stone texture node group do?

Tags: node-editor, procedural

I am following a procedural stone texture tutorial and they showed this node group, this acts as the starting point for pretty much the whole texture, but I have no idea what it does. It basically takes texture coordinate object, separates xyz, and then subtracts data from object info[image]

Wouldn't this do the same thing?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely trying to add some randomness into the texture coordinates so all objects don't have a perfectly matching texture placement introducing some variation between them despite using the same texture.

It takes *Object* texture coordinates as base then separates each axis into separate components so an arbitrary value can be subtracted to in each direction (*Color* for X, *Object Index* for Y and *Random* for Z) and it doesn't always offset the same amount for each axis.

I do have some doubts about its real effectiveness, since as far as I know both *Index* and *Color* aren't really random, but is user adjustable values.
On the other hand it does allow some degree of "manual placement" on per-object level.

Comment: I want more of your answers, please! I always learn a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks, you've been doing great too. Keep it up

Comment: So I could recreate this using only a texture coordinate random node?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such node exists by default

Comment: You can see on the texture coordinate node, there's a random vector, couldn't I avoid everything with Texture coordinate (random) to whatever the combine xyz is connected to?

Comment: Read again what the socket label says

Comment: What about Object info's random?