# why are all textures for all objects the same?

Tags: shader-nodes

Beginner texture question:

I thought, if i took object coordinates, the noise textures etc. would have different values so that the material doesn't look the same.

Unfortunately they look the same.

So it looks like i misunderstood here something!?

[image]

material:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See what object texture coordinates are https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles/56613#56613 Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186953/what-does-this-stone-texture-node-group-do/186957#186957

Comment: thanks Duarte....i used now geometry position, that was what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use an *Object Info* node's *Random* or *Object Index* values to create variations. Here's a contrived example where the *Object Index* is used to control the *W* value of a 4d *Noise* texture while a random value is added to its scale to change the scale slightly.

*W* is often used as a "seed" in *Noise* textures. The downside is that 4d noise is computationally expensive, but you can use the *Random* value to randomize any parameter.

This has a slight advantage in animation: Using *Position* means that textures will "swim" as you move objects.  On the other hand, if you want the swimming effect, then *Position* is exactly what you want.

[image: Randomizing a noise texture with overkill]

Comment: you are right, i just wonder why in my "special" case my solution worked....but it was a more complicated material from a library. But in the easy case i tried you are totally right! thanks!